# Why my regex matches non-ascii characters?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm trying to filter anything except alphanumeric characters, Russian letters, line breaks, spaces, commas, dots, question marks, exclamation marks, slashes, `#`, `@`, colons and parentheses.

My regex so far: `r"[^А-я\w\d\n ,.?!ё/@#:()]"`

However, it does not match the following string: `""`.
Why not, and how can I make it do so?

**Edit:** Forgot to mention that it works as expected at https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check the string at [this link](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%F0%9D%95%BE%F0%9D%96%8D%F0%9D%96%8E%F0%9D%96%97%F0%9D%96%94%F0%9D%96%93#title) and you will see that the  "" string consists of characters belonging to `\p{L}` category. Your regex starts with `[^А-я\w\d`, which means it matches any chars but Russian chars (except `ё` (that you define a bit later) and `Ё`), any Unicode letters (**any** because in Python 3, `\w` - by default - matches any Unicode alphanumeric chars and connector punctuation.

It appears you only want to remove Russian and English letters, so use the corresponding ranges:

```
r"[^А-ЯЁа-яёA-Za-z0-9\n ,.?!/@#:()]+"
```

It matches one or more chas other than

- `А-ЯЁа-яё` - Russian letters
- `A-Za-z` - ASCII letters
- `0-9` - ASCII digits
- `\n ,.?!/@#:()` - newline, space, comma, dot, question and exclamation marks, slash, ampersand, hash, colon and round parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it so it only matches the type you need. Instead of the string type that you don't need.

This should work `[А-я\w\d\"+\"\n\"+\" ,.?!ё/@#:()]`

Comment: Always test it through https://regex101.com/ and `Python` option